# MySql show details in single row

Tags: mysql

I have a query which returns for a particular user data in multiple rows as folows,

[image]

And the query for above result as below,

SELECT user_id,route_id,route_schedule_id FROM `um.user_rm.route` WHERE user_id IN
(
   SELECT UR.user_id FROM `um.user_rm.route` UR
             INNER JOIN `um.user_waitinglist` UW ON UW.user_id=UR.user_id
             WHERE UR.route_schedule_id=43
);

My requirement is to get the details in single row as below,

[image]

Any suggessions,

Thanks in advance
Sangeetha

Comment: um.user_rm.route is the actual name of a table?

Comment: Yes it is the actual name.um indicates user management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT user_id, route_id, CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(route_schedule_id) AS CHAR) AS schedules
FROM um.user_rm.route
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT UR.user_id
    FROM um.user_rm.route UR
    INNER JOIN um.user_waitinglist UW ON UW.user_id=UR.user_id WHERE UR.route_schedule_id=43
)
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: This gives me only one schedule. I want both schdules, i am getting it. But need to find if any possibility to get in single row

Answer (score 0):

I successfully done the query and got the output as required. Below is my query,

```
SELECT R1.user_id,R1.route_id AS Route1,R1.route_schedule_id AS Schedule1,
       R2.route_id AS Route2,R2.route_schedule_id AS Schedule2 FROM `um.user_rm.route` R1 
INNER JOIN `um.user_rm.route` R2 ON R1.user_id=R2.user_id AND R1.user_route_id > R2.user_route_id
WHERE R1.user_id  IN
(
  SELECT UR.user_id FROM `um.user_rm.route` UR
             INNER JOIN `um.user_waitinglist` UW ON UW.user_id=UR.user_id
             WHERE UR.route_schedule_id=43
)
GROUP BY R1.user_id
```